# the Wi-Fi Connection doesn't work and the airplane mode is always on

Tags: networking

The airplane mode is always on in my labtop so the Wi-Fi doesn't work 
Even when I close it and make the Wi-Fi on it turns off in 1 second 
The output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command is:

```
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:635 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/hp.conf line 2: ignoring bad line starting with 'j'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:635 kmodb'onfig_parse: /etc/modprobe.libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:635 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/hp.conf line 4: ignoring bad line starting with 'k'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:635 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/hp.conf line 5: ignoring bad line starting with 'j'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:635 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/hp.conf line 6: ignoring bad line starting with 'k'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:635 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/hp.conf line 7: ignoring bad line starting with 'k'
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
    DeviceName: Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi Adapter
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter [103c:18ec]
Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci.                                                  0: phy0: witless lan.    
Soft blocked: no                                            
hard blocked: yes
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: The output of( lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list )in terminal command is.                                                           lspci-knn : command not found                                          0: phy0: witless lan.    Soft blocked: no                                            
                                       hard blocked: yes

Comment: It is not `lspci-knn`, but `lspci -knn`

Comment: And then.......

Comment: You have crap in `/etc/modprobe.d/hp.conf`.

Comment: how could i fix this problem or there are not simple solution for this ????